# inline form with django crispy form

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm sorry but I just don't get it, the [docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-inline-forms) here are pretty awesome, and I'm using practically the same example, I just have two fields, that I want do display inline, but it's just does not work,

My form:

```
from django import forms

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms import layout, bootstrap
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import InlineField, FormActions, StrictButton
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout

from ..models import EmployeeModel


class EmployeeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    TODO: Extend CompanyModel into Form
    :returns: TODO
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.method = "POST"
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.field_template = 'bootstrap3/layout/inline_field.html'
        self.helper.form_action = "company:create-employee"

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            StrictButton('Add', css_class='btn-default'),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name"]
```

and my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'why' %}">WHY SCREEN?</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'faq' %}">FAQ</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p style="padding:60px;"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
      <form action="{% url 'company:create-employee' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% crispy form %}
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But still the form is rendered horizontally and it's not inline, so what I'm I missing here can someone explain me please.

Comment: according to docs {% crispy form form.helper  %} shall work

Comment: I've got it, I'll answer it now, yup that might work, but I've used `Div` class from`crispy_forms.bootstrap import Div`

Comment: Note that if you name your FormHelper attribute helper you will only need to do:{% crispy form %}

Comment: perfect example to use crispy forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I've got it, It goes like this

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import formset_factory

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms import layout, bootstrap
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import InlineField, FormActions, StrictButton, Div
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout
from crispy_forms import bootstrap, layout

from company.models.employee_model import EmployeeModel


class EmployeeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    TODO: Extend CompanyModel into Form
    :returns: TODO
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.method = "POST"
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.field_template = 'bootstrap3/layout/inline_field.html'
        self.helper.form_action = "company:create-employee"

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Div('first_name', css_class="col-sm-2"),
            Div('last_name', css_class="col-sm-2"),
            Div('middle_initial', css_class="col-sm-2"),
            Div('social_security_number', css_class="col-sm-2"),
            bootstrap.FormActions(
                layout.Submit('submit', 'Add', css_class='btn btn-primary')),
            css_class='row',
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "middle_initial", "social_security_number"]
```

I've used `Div` and `css_class='row'`, also I've added `css_class` to the `Div's` and it works perfectly. The form is displayed inline now.

Answer (score 0):

Crispy Forms [layouts](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html) also let you do this via:

```
InlineCheckboxes('field_name')
```